# System suspend instead of shutting down

Tags: shutdown, suspend

My system gets suspended when I turn off the power supply. It only happen when I use Ubuntu OS. How can I solve this problem? I am using Toshiba Satellite Series Laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you're using either the Shutdown option from the power menu in Unity, or by invoking `sudo reboot -p`. What is your hardware?

(Sorry, can't comment on questions yet)

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you did not understood my problem correctly. When I switch off my power supply, it automatically suspends after a fraction of seconds. It really irritates me while I'm working.

Comment: Does it have any thing to do with hardware?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I saw the edit just now. What do you mean 'it automatically suspends'? Go into hibernate instead of turning off?

Comment: I don't want the system to be hibernated or be suspended. It is just that I'm charging my system, when I unplug it when it gets fully charged, it says battery critically low and gets suspended. (If you ask about the battery, The battery is working just fine giving me 2 or 3 hours of backup)